# How to pad a set of tensors to a specific height

Tags: python, pytorch, padding, truncate

I am doing action recognition with mediapipe keypoints.
These are the shapes of some of my tensors:

> torch.Size([3, 3, 75]) torch.Size([3, 6, 75]) torch.Size([3, 10, 75])
> torch.Size([3, 11, 75]) torch.Size([3, 9, 75]) torch.Size([3, 4, 75])
> torch.Size([3, 21, 75])

The height of each tensor varies as they refer to the number of frames for each sample.

I have decided that I want to consider 8 frames for each sample. I understand I have to do padding and truncate (for heights above 8), but somehow just doing the padding worked, or so it seems. I wish to understand how my code worked.

```
if height < 8:
            source_pad = F.pad(tensor1, pad=(0, 0, 0, 8 - height))
        else:
            source_pad = F.pad(tensor1, pad=(0,0, 0, 8 - height))
```

Comment: Would it be OK to just do image resize?

Comment: They are not images but are mediapipe keypoints saved as numpy files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.pad.html#torch.nn.functional.pad) the `pad` arguments are specified working backwards from last dimension, so you pad the last dimension by 1 on each side and the second-to-last dimension by 0 at the start and `8-height` at the end. `8-height` works out to be positive if `height` is less than 8, 0 if `height` = 8, and negative if `height` is greater than 8.

In other words, `resulting height` = `height` + 0 + (8-`height`) = 8.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. Does this mean a height above 8 will have a size of negative?